# DataReader.Read() always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, oracle, datareader

I've been searching for hours now. I can't find anything helpful for my problem.
The Read()-function always returns false. If I run the SQL-command with sqlplus I get this result:

```
   GERA_ID   GETY_BEZEICHNUNG
   ---------------------------
    100001   Blackberry
    100002   GSM
```

here's a simplified version of the code:

```
List<Divice> divices = new List<Divice>();

using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select gera_id, gety_bezeichnung from idc_geraet, idc_geraettyp where idc_geraettyp.gety_id = idc_geraet.gety_id and pers_id = 4711");
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    connection.Open();
    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read()) //returns always false
    {
        Divice g = new Divice();
        g.gera_id = reader.GetDecimal(0);
        g.gety_bezeichnung = reader.GetString(1);
        divices.Add(g);
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

**EDIT:**

This Code is called before. and it works fine:

```
IDC_PERSON p = new IDC_PERSON();
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select PERS_VNAME, PERS_NNAME, PERS_EINTRDATUM from idc_person where PERS_ID = 4711");
        cmd.Connection = connection;

        connection.Open();
        OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            p.PERS_ID = user_id;
            p.PERS_VNAME = reader.GetString(0);
            p.PERS_NNAME = reader.GetString(1);
            p.PERS_EINTRDATUM = reader.GetDateTime(2);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
```

So, here is the whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using TelKoOpt.Models;
using System.Data;

namespace TelKoOpt.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        string connectionString = "user id=scott;password=tiger;" +
                "data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)" +
                "(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))";
        public ActionResult Index(int user_id)
        {
            MyDbContext dbcontext = new MyDbContext();
            IDC_PERSON p = new IDC_PERSON();
            List<IDC_GERAET> geraete = new List<IDC_GERAET>();
            List<TELGSMEGN> telgsmegn = new List<TELGSMEGN>();
            dbcontext.pers = p;
            dbcontext.geraete = geraete;
            dbcontext.telgsmegn = telgsmegn;

            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select PERS_VNAME, PERS_NNAME, PERS_EINTRDATUM from idc_person where PERS_ID = " + user_id);
                //OracleCommand cmdTelg = new OracleCommand("select service, sum(betrag), sum(dauer), sum(anzahl), zonen from test_telgsmegn where gera_id = " + user_id + " and datumaktion between '" + "01.02.2012" + "' and '" + "20.03.2012" + "' group by service, zonen; ");
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                //cmdTelg.Connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        p.PERS_ID = user_id;
                        p.PERS_VNAME = reader.GetString(0);
                        p.PERS_NNAME = reader.GetString(1);
                        p.PERS_EINTRDATUM = reader.GetDateTime(2);
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (OracleException)
                {
                    //return View(dbcontext);
                }
            }
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select gera_id, gety_bezeichnung from idc_geraet, idc_geraettyp where idc_geraettyp.gety_id = idc_geraet.gety_id and pers_id = " + user_id);
                cmd.Connection = connection;

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while(reader.Read()) 
                    {
                        IDC_GERAET g = new IDC_GERAET();
                        g.gera_id = reader.GetDecimal(0);
                        g.gety_bezeichnung = reader.GetString(1);
                        geraete.Add(g);
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (OracleException)
                {
                    //return View(dbcontext);
                }
            }
            return View(dbcontext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the duplicated   `reader.Read();` inside the loop.

Comment: @leonbloy True, but doesn't solve his problem. Did you try to simplify the query into something very basic, just to test the code?

Comment: Oh thanks, i didn't see that. But this isn't the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't post it as an aswer :-)

Comment: @Yorye The sql-command works fine, but the Read() also returns false when i use a simple command like 'select gera_id from idc_geraet where pers_id = 4711'

Comment: Go simpler. Test `select * from idc_geraet`.

Comment: @YoryeNathan i've tried it. it doesn't help either. When i debug it does't go into the loop

Comment: Try to alter the DB instead of getting info. Maybe the problem isn't with the reader, but with the connection. Perform an `Insert`. Also, is this called as the first thing that communicates with the DB? You're forgetting to close the connection and that can mess things up as well.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle, but does it need a ; at the end of the select? So your code would be: OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select gera_id, gety_bezeichnung from idc_geraet, idc_geraettyp where idc_geraettyp.gety_id = idc_geraet.gety_id and pers_id = 4711;");

Comment: @YoryeNathan see on my post. i updated it

Comment: @Paritosh no it doesn't need a ;

Comment: *Syntax is fine* ... *query works in database* (according to you)... problem is in the connection. Can we see the connection string ?

Comment: Are you sure you're working with the same database, I.E. the connection string correctly configured?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk the Connection works. I get some Data out before the code which doesn't work is called.

Comment: @YoryeNathan nothing changes. it is useles.

Comment: Could you test it when the code that doesn't work runs first? Let's try it as a first communication with the DB.

Comment: @YoryeNathan the second part is called first. i'll post the hole code

Comment: I think you should put the field names in uppercase

Comment: Is your actual SQL doing a select? Or a print? Or...?

Comment: @Siwar that won't help

Comment: @MarcGravell what do you mean?

Comment: @Siwar Case doesn't matter.

Comment: Swap the two `using` blocks. Let the non-working code run first. Does it now work, and the other one doesn't?

Comment: @YoryeNathan No, it's the same. the one that was the second stil doesn't work. and the other does.

Comment: @user I mainly want to know if the example SQL is even remotely like the actual SQL

Comment: @MarcGravell i've posted the real code with the actual SQL

Comment: Triple check the DB connection string and query, to be sure that they are the same ones that you use on the SQLPlus Manager. There's something silly that we're missing.

Comment: @YoryeNathan ok, i checked it and found out sth strange. when i run the command with sqldeveloper it works. when i run it with sqlplus - no result. the command `select * from idc_person` with sqlplus works. the command `select * from idc_geraet` doesn't work with sqlplus (no result). in sqldeveloper both commands work.

Comment: Triple check that they are connected to the same DB, with the same credentials and permissions (grants).

Comment: Yes, i've got only on db (local), both use the scheme scott. watch this -> http://www.pic-upload.de/view-19225275/Untitled.png.html

Comment: I don't have the slightest clue what can cause this, but I suggest closing this question and posting a new one, DB related, since you've found the real issue.

Comment: The problem was that i forgot the commit after updating the data in the idc_geraet table

Comment: does not make sense to me, except if you were connecting with different users... And even with that, you would have a lock timeout warning somewhere

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer for your case, but I ran into a similar issue when debugging code and it may help others who come across this question.

The solution I figured out was actually only specific to when you are debugging. When stepping through code, if you expand the "Results View" (which enumerates the enumerable), when you get to the part in your code that reads the data reader, the reader will already be at the end of the results, and will return false. This is because data readers are forward only, and once you've enumerated to the next result (which was done by the debugger in this case), you can't go back.

Answer (score -1):

same issue faced by me this is how i fixed

use out type

```
 public void ExecuteStoredProcReturnDataReader(string sQueryName, out IDataReader dr, List<DBParam> oParams =null)
    {


        try
        {
            dbHelper DBProvider = new dbHelper();
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            oCmd = DBProvider.CreateCommand(sQueryName, conn);

            if (oParams !=null)
            DBProvider.CreateParameters(oParams, ref oCmd);

            dr = oCmd.ExecuteReader();




        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            rethrow = DataAccessExceptionHandler.HandleException(ref e);
            if (rethrow)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            dr = null;  
        }

    }
```